# Unstructured grouping data from excel to sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

[image]

```
date    code    employee    type    total   actual
12-12-2018  ltsdysa 3026262 general 150 139
            typical 200 177
            dummy   120 100
14-12-2018  hskdbegs    3630878 new 300 143
            typical 100 99
        4829264 dummy   210 187
            general 130 89
            typical 200 200
18-12-2018  tuebdhxj    3637980 old 300 143
            typical 100 99
        4833390 general 300 260
            typical 130 89
            new 200 200
```

Hi all , i want to import the excel data into sql table. The sample data is given in above picture.
I need to insert the data of the date ,code, employee column data against their respective type column.

**Expected output**

[image]

Can you please help me out with the ssis tasks.
Its like i need to ungroup first 3 columns.

Comment: You should at least show us what the expected SQL table would look like.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry am not able to provide the snapshot. But am pasting it in the above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have added snapshot of the output what i want in sql table. I need to create a package where i need to convert the above picture data from excel to sql table.

Comment: You would need some sort of Row Number number to ensure the proper Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you have to solve that problem:

1.Create staging table in your DB like this. Keep in mind that you need to have Identity column while you are inserting:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Excel_stg (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Date] VARCHAR(50),
    code VARCHAR(50),
    Employee VARCHAR(50),
    [type] VARCHAR(50),
    total VARCHAR(50),
    actual VARCHAR(50)
)
```

2.Build SSIS package to load Excel data into your staging table.

3.Run following query to extract corrected data (I've included some data for testing purposes)

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Excel_stg ([Date],code,Employee,type,total,actual)
VALUES ('2018-12-12','Itsdysa','3026262','general','150','139');
GO
INSERT INTO tbl_Excel_stg ([Date],code,Employee,type,total,actual)
VALUES ('','','','typica','200','177');
GO
INSERT INTO tbl_Excel_stg ([Date],code,Employee,type,total,actual)
VALUES ('','','','dummy','120','100');
GO
INSERT INTO tbl_Excel_stg ([Date],code,Employee,type,total,actual)
VALUES ('2018-12-14','hskdbegs','3630878','new','300','143');
GO
INSERT INTO tbl_Excel_stg ([Date],code,Employee,type,total,actual)
VALUES ('','','','typical','100','99');
GO
INSERT INTO tbl_Excel_stg ([Date],code,Employee,type,total,actual)
VALUES ('','','4829264','dummy','210','187');
GO
INSERT INTO tbl_Excel_stg ([Date],code,Employee,type,total,actual)
VALUES ('','','','general','130','89');
GO

SELECT [Date] = CASE s0.[Date] WHEN '' THEN s1.[Date] ELSE s0.[Date] END
    , code = CASE s0.code WHEN '' THEN s1.code ELSE s0.code END
    , Employee = CASE s0.Employee WHEN '' THEN s1.Employee ELSE s0.Employee END
    , s0.type, s0.total, s0.actual
FROM tbl_Excel_stg as s0
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT ID = MAX(si.ID) FROM tbl_Excel_stg as si
    WHERE si.ID < s0.ID and si.[Date] != ''
) as sDate
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT ID = MAX(si.ID) FROM tbl_Excel_stg as si
    WHERE si.ID < s0.ID and si.code != ''
) as scode
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT ID = MAX(si.ID) FROM tbl_Excel_stg as si
    WHERE si.ID < s0.ID and si.Employee != ''
) as sEmployee
LEFT JOIN tbl_Excel_stg as s1 ON s1.ID = sDate.ID
LEFT JOIN tbl_Excel_stg as s2 ON s2.ID = scode.ID
LEFT JOIN tbl_Excel_stg as s3 ON s3.ID = sEmployee.ID
ORDER BY s0.ID
```

The solution might be not very beautiful, but simple to understand/change/debug

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS, you can achieve this using a Script Component:

1. Add a DataFlow Task
2. In the Data Flow Task, add an Excel Source, a Script Component and an OLEDB Destination
3. In the Script Component add 3 new output columns (`outdate`, `outcode` and `outemployee`) having the same data types as the source columns
4. In the Script component select `Visual Basic` as Script language
5. In the Script editor write the following code:

   ```
   Private Lastdate as string
   Private LastEmployee as string
   Private Lastcode as string

   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

   If Not Row.date_IsNull Then

       Row.outdate = Row.date
       Lastdate = Row.date
   Else

       Row.outdate = Lastdate

   End If

   If Not Row.employee_IsNull Then

       Row.outemployee = Row.employee
       Lastemployee = Row.employee
   Else

       Row.outemployee = Lastemployee

   End If

   If Not Row.code_IsNull Then

       Row.outcode = Row.code
       Lastcode = Row.code
   Else

       Row.outcode = Lastcode

   End If




   End Sub
   ```
6. Map the new created columns and `type`, `total` and `actual` columns to the relevant destination column